# ionic google map javascript android device unable to get current location

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ionic-framework

```js
var exampleApp= angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
exampleApp.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
 
   
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
 
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
draggable: true,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

 });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Location"
            });
        });
 
        $scope.map = map;
    });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="MapController">
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
            <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1oJGDZP2lM3c1dnPBmAbPBOb_Rh4u8n0&sensor=true"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This part is the javascript and html part of the code

> I dont undestand why the google map unable to get user current location in android device but it work on ios simulator i will be very grateful if anyone of you can help me to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bad idea to use `navigator` directly in ionic, i would recommend using `ngCordova` and its powerful plugins for cross platform features:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/

Apart from this I would also check if you have enabled geolocation for your app.

You should see something like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: ya i added those two permission already so what is the error then mukkamala?

Comment: any console errors? networks requests in pending state? Also, Not all android support navigator, so try using the ngcordova plugin instead

Comment: how to use ngcordova can you give me a code sample?

Comment: can you edit my js code file above with ngcordova example cause i am really a noob and beginner for ionic

Comment: Here are steps to install ngcodova in your app : http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/